# Displaying all associated record information in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am building an events agenda page which has a list of sessions and the speakers associated to those sessions but im getter an undefined method on the speaker information

#### View

```
<% @event.sessions.day_1.each do |s| %>
  <%= s.time.strftime("%H:%M") %>
  <%= s.title %>
  <%= s.speaker.name %>
  <%= s.speaker.company %>
<% end %>
```

#### Controller

```
def index
  @sessions = Session.all
end
```

#### Speaker Model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :sessions
```

#### Session Model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :events
has_and_belongs_to_many :speakers

scope :day_1, where(day: 'Day 1')
scope :day_2, where(day: 'Day 2')

default_scope -> { order_by("time ASC") }
```

#### Event Model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :sessions
```

Error

```
undefined method `name?' for "536f3cd4ad921dd345000001":String
```

Comment: Speaker `belongs_to :session` and Session `has_and_belongs_to_many :speaker` just doesn't make sense.

Comment: in this line: `<% @event.sessions.day_1.each do |s| %>`, what is `day_1`? is it an attribute of `sessions`? can you post your `schema.rb`

Comment: day_1 is to scoped to a day field in the DB.

Comment: The association above isn't right. A Session has 1 speaker. A Speaker can belong to many sessions. What should the correct association be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your associations between speaker and sessions are messed up.  IF you want Session HABTM speakers, you also need Speaker HABTM sessions.

EDIT:

After some discussion, this is what you are looking for.  Speaker `has_many :sessions` & Session `belongs_to :speaker` with the foreign key speaker_id in the session table.

Comment: ok.. the error says undefined method `name?` are you sure there isn't a typo in your view that you are accidentally calling `name?` rather than `name`?

Comment: Also, s.speaker shouldn't work because you session has many speakers.  The method `speaker` on a session doesn't exist, but `speakers` does.

Comment: Definitely no typo, Actually a Session has 1 speaker. A Speaker can belong to many sessions. What should the correct association be?

Comment: so what you are going for is actually Speaker `has_many :sessions` & Session `belongs_to :speaker`  with the foreign key `speaker_id` in the session table.

Comment: Yes, that associated corrected all my issues! Thanks you very much :)

Comment: excellent.  I'll edit my answer to include it.  would be so kind as to accept the answer?